# Absolute Continuity of $x^a \sin(x^{-b})$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How do I show $\displaystyle{x^{a}\sin\left(1 \over x^{b}\right)\quad}$ on (0,1] is absolutely continuous iff $\displaystyle{a > b\,\,\,\,\,}$? ( only using epsilons and deltas ).

See wikipedia definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

I have spent a ton of time on it, and I am really lost because I am sure the fact that $\displaystyle{a > b\,\,\,\,\,}$ must mean that power of a is squeezing the function down around the origin, while the greater b gets the more is oscillates. I am just at a complete loss about how to show this. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by showing that it does not have bounded variation when $0<a\leq b$ (look at partition points when $\frac{1}{x^b}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$), and that it is the integral of its derivative when $a>b>0$.

Comment: That does solves the problem of showing when it is not continuous, but I can't use the fact that it is the integral of its derivative, I can only use epsilons and deltas. This is why I am stuck. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @Carter: You can use epsilons and deltas to prove that it is the integral of its derivative when $a>b>0$.  (If $a\geq b+1$ and $b>0$ then you can show that the function has bounded derivative hence it Lipschitz, but that leaves $b<a<b+1$.)